# PHP decimal rounding error

Tags: php, floor

```
$duration = 35780.123000; // duration in seconds.

$milliseconds = $duration - floor($duration);
echo $milliseconds
// 0.12299999999959
```

How do I extract the milliseconds 0.123000 without freaky rounding errors?
I need to keep 6 decimals for precision. (So not 0.123)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo number_format($milliseconds,6);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
number_format($number, 6)
```

Comment: Nope, it still cuts trailing zero's so I end up with 0.123, not 0.123000

Comment: From where do you get 0.12299999999959?

Comment: Just the stupid php. It's random decimal when it should be perfect 0.123000. Try the exact code I used and see for yourself.

Comment: Maybe I should just go for explode and manipulate it as a string.. -_-".

Comment: @HugoCox - the stupid computer.... PHP is simply a programming language that uses IEEE754 for floating point representation, the same as almost every other programming language.... but [round() works perfectly well](https://3v4l.org/CMLiP), or use `sprintf()` instead, or `number_format()`

Comment: @MarkBaker As mentioned, I need to keep the trailing zero's, so round() doesn't work for me. Have you tried my example? I already tried sprintf().

Comment: Have you tried `sprintf()` or `number_format()` that are intended for display formatting rather than `round()` which is intended for rounding

Comment: @DrimadesBoy Thank you, that worked! Please update your answer so I can mark it as correct.